# Serializing XML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, xml, express

I am consuming XML in express server parsing it with `express-xml-bodyparser`, but the resulting object is basically unusable.

XML

```
<SubClass code="A07.0"/>
<SubClass code="A07.1"/>
<SubClass code="A07.2"/>
<SubClass code="A07.3"/>
<SubClass code="A07.8"/>
<SubClass code="A07.9"/>
```

is serialized as JSON

```
subclass:
[ { '$': { code: 'A07.0' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.1' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.2' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.3' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.8' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.9' } } ]
```

Is there way to pase it directly into

```
subclass: ['A07.0','A07.1','A07.2','A07.3','A07.8','A07.9']
```

or some easy way how to convert it into this array?

Comment: `Array.from(parentNode.childNodes).filter(n => n.nodeType === 1).map(n => n.getAttribute('code'))`

Comment: Under what logic would a serializer know to do what you're describing? What if the XML looked like this, what should it do then: `<SubClass code="A07.0"/>
<SubClass code="A07.1"/>
<SubClass code="A07.2" subCode="5"/>
<Field id="9" />
<SubClass code="A07.3"/>
<SubClass code="A07.8"/>
<SubClass code="A07.9"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [mergeAttrs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js#options) option to `true` in order to remove `$` properties:

```
 xmlparser({ mergeAttrs: true, explicitArray: false})
```

Output:

```
SubClass: [
    { code: "A07.0" },
    { code: "A07.1" },
    { code: "A07.2" },
    { code: "A07.3" },
    { code: "A07.8" },
    { code: "A07.9" }
]
```

Or you can just use [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
var data = { subclass:
[ { '$': { code: 'A07.0' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.1' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.2' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.3' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.8' } },
  { '$': { code: 'A07.9' } } ] };
  
  
var result = data.subclass.map( (obj) => {
    return obj.$.code;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert json into an object then maybe something like...

```
var arr = Object.keys(json).map(function(x) { return obj[x] });
```

With jQuery

```
var arr = $.map(json, function(x) { return x});
```

Comment: This wouldn't work on the "JSON" that OP posted, and I think OP is looking to skip intermediate JSON step.